# Executar php dentro de uma condição javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Tem como executar php dentro de uma condição javascript?

Exemplo:

```
<script>
if(variaveljs==2){
  <?php
  $variavelphp=20;
  ?>
}
</script>
```

Comment: O que tem de mal esse código?

Comment: Você pode fazer o que quiser desta forma aí. Mais sempre que for passar o valor para o JavaScript tem que escrever os valores com echo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O PHP corre no lado do servidor, e este corre sempre primeiro que o código de de Javascript, que corre no cliente.
Por isso essa condição não irá trabalhar, se pretendes enviar dados do cliente para o servidor tens de usar ajax

Comment: tive estudando um pouquinho do jquery, o qual eu ja tinha usado mas nunca entendi muito bem, e consegui resolver o problema metendo o codigo php em outra página e usando a função load. Muito Obrigado :)